# Issue while accessing WSDL from proxy url

Tags: java, web-services, soap, proxy, wsdl

I have created a soap based web service and deployed on my local server (Tomcat).

Now I pointed one of the proxy server (hosted on internet) to my local server.

When I access the WSDL from proxy url, schemalocation is coming with the local server url.

```
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-              wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy"             name="MovieServiceImplService">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://movies.media.com/" schemaLocation="***http://123.13.33.44:8888/ws-test/Movietest?xsd=1***"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="searchByTitle">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:searchByTitle"/>
</message>
<message name="searchByTitleResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:searchByTitleResponse"/>
</message>
....

My proxy url is https://abcd:8990. I want the schemalocation to be https://abcd:8990/ws-test/Movietest?xsd=1
```

Can somebody tell me what changes can be done to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried to use a relative path or a server absolute path of the xsd file into your schemaLocation?

Comment: You should make use of ProxyPreserveHost directive of Apache mod_proxy module

Comment: Not an answer, but have you looked at using SoapUI, free, open source, minutes to install. great for developing and troubleshooting when starting up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Keerthi Ramanathan.

```
   You should make use of ProxyPreserveHost directive of Apache mod_proxy module
```

This worked for me. But there was one issue left. My apache server was https and the schemalocation url was becoming http url. I could not understand the reason. Do you have any idea what could have been done for this?

For now, I have removed ssl.